# how to scramble an image into regular patches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

I need to patch images into let say 3x3 patches, or any regualr patches, then shuffle them and after that reassemble the image. I tried to use `patchify` but it gives eerror for unpatchify.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from patchify import patchify, unpatchify
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import shuffle
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import requests


transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Resize((224,224)),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

url = 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/bright-forget-me-nots-royalty-free-image-1677788394.jpg'
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

plt.imshow(transform(image).permute(1,2,0))
```

I looks like the following before shuffling or patchfying

[image]

```
patched_image = patchify(np.array(image), (100, 100, 3), 100)
shuffled_patches = np.random.shuffle(patched_image)
output_image = unpatchify(shuffled_patches, np.array(image).shape)
```

The error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-0b9963e642b8> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 output_image = unpatchify(shuffled_patches, np.array(image).shape)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patchify/__init__.py in unpatchify(patches, imsize)
     52     """
     53 
---> 54     assert len(patches.shape) / 2 == len(
     55         imsize
     56     ), "The patches dimension is not equal to the original image size"

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.random.shuffle` does not return anything, it shuffles the given input in place, see [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html). This is similar to the standard routine `sort()`.

This shows up, when attempting to use the returned `None` during `unpatchify`.

If you want to keep the previous state as well, maybe the copy module may assist in creating a clone before shuffling, `org_image = copy.copy(patched_image)` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks but I need to stre the shuffled version. and copy does not work :(

Comment: @Rainbow: "does not work" is lacking details. Did you try `deepcopy()` instead?